# How to fix Linker's broken paths?

Tags: 16.04, compiling, ld

I am trying to build a repo on my Ubuntu 16.04 from a source and everything goes fine until it reaches the files linked to OpenCV.

I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lIlmImf
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibjasper
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibtiff
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibpng
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibjpeg
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lzlib
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:305: recipe for target 'lib/libmxnet.so' failed
make: *** [lib/libmxnet.so] Error 1
```

So I tried to check what the linker is actually doing. I typed

```
ld - llibjpeg --verbose
```

and got

```
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblibjpeg.so failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblibjpeg.a failed
attempt to open //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblibjpeg.so failed
attempt to open //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblibjpeg.a failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblibjpeg.so failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblibjpeg.a failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib64/liblibjpeg.so failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib64/liblibjpeg.a failed
attempt to open //lib64/liblibjpeg.so failed
attempt to open //lib64/liblibjpeg.a failed
attempt to open //usr/lib64/liblibjpeg.so failed
attempt to open //usr/lib64/liblibjpeg.a failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/liblibjpeg.so failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/liblibjpeg.a failed
attempt to open //lib/liblibjpeg.so failed
attempt to open //lib/liblibjpeg.a failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/liblibjpeg.so failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/liblibjpeg.a failed
attempt to open //usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib64/liblibjpeg.so failed
attempt to open //usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib64/liblibjpeg.a failed
attempt to open //usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/liblibjpeg.so failed
attempt to open //usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/liblibjpeg.a failed
ld: cannot find -llibjpeg
```

As we see, the linker is not looking for the right file! On the other hand, if I type

```
ld - ljpeg --verbose
```

I see this:

```
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.a failed
attempt to open //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so failed
attempt to open //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.a failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so succeeded
-ljpeg (//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so)
libc.so.6 needed by //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so
found libc.so.6 at //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 needed by //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
found ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 at //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; not setting start address
```

So the libjpeg library IS there, the linker is simply looking for a wrong file.

In the makefile I have

```
ifeq ($(USE_OPENCV), 1)
        CFLAGS += -DMXNET_USE_OPENCV=1 $(shell pkg-config --cflags opencv)
        LDFLAGS += $(filter-out -lopencv_ts, $(shell pkg-config --libs opencv))
        BIN += bin/im2rec
```

And the paths indicated by the shell scripts `pkg-config --cflags opencv` and `pkg-config --libs opencv` are correct.

I'd be grateful for any help with the fix.

EDIT: I run `make uninstall` in the OpenCV source folder. After that, the build passed succesfully. Very strange, seems like OpenCV messed up the symlinks. I played with opencv.pc files earlier and the paths were missing or wrong.

Comment: What exactly is the output of `pkg-config --libs opencv`? it seems odd that it would contain `-llibtiff`, `-llibjpeg`, etc. rather than `-ltiff`, `-ljpeg` (since these are expanded to `liblibtiff.so`, `liblibjpeg.so` and so on - the `lib` prefix will get duplicated)

Comment: The output is: 
`-L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_nonfree -lopencv_superres -lopencv_ocl -lopencv_ts -lopencv_videostab -lopencv_gpu -lopencv_photo -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_video -lopencv_ml -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_highgui -lIlmImf -llibjasper -llibtiff -llibpng -llibjpeg -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_flann -lopencv_core -lzlib -lQtCore -lQtTest -lQtGui -lQtOpenGL -lcufft -lGL -lGLU -lrt -lpthread -lm -ldl -lstdc++ -lnpps -lnppi -lnppc -lcudart`
Clearly some libraries have correct paths, but not all.

Comment: Another idea - are you sure that `ld -ljpeg --verbose` is a correct syntax? Where did you see it? `sudo ldconfig -v | grep jpeg`. `pkg-config --libs libjpeg` will return `-ljpeg` as expected.

Comment: The command `pkg-config --libs libjpeg` indeed returns `-ljpeg`. On the other hand, the command  `pkg-config --libs libtiff` returns `Package libtiff was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing 'libtiff.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libtiff' found`. 
I also tried `pkg-config --libs libtiff-4` and got `-ltiff`, so the package is there...

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand where you got problem. I have compiled it successfully (even without `sudo apt-get build-dep libopencv-dev`):

```
wget https://github.com/opencv/opencv/archive/2.4.13.5.zip
unzip 2.4.13.5.zip
cd opencv-2.4.13.5
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make -j16
sudo make install
```

And then `pkg-config --libs opencv` shows the following:

> -L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_core -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_flann -lopencv_gpu -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_ml -lopencv_nonfree -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_ocl -lopencv_photo -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_superres -lopencv_ts -lopencv_video -lopencv_videostab -lrt -lpthread -lm -ldl

and `pkg-config --cflags opencv`

> -I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/include

Comment: The problem is I installed OpenCV as a build from source, not from a repo. Is it possible that having proceeded this way the system hasn't updated LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

Comment: This command will install all libs and headers which are needed for successful compilation. From where you downloaded OpenCV source?

Comment: I got it from GitHub: (https://github.com/opencv/opencv/archive/2.4.13.5.zip). Afterwards (after I got the error) I also installed the package libopencv-dev via apt-get, so now I have two...

Comment: The problem is that the names of these few directories that ld couldn't find are shown improperly by pkg-config. And I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: The main difference is that I have Intel GPU. May be Nvidia CUDA changes directories and compilation process on your system. On my hardware I can't reproduce this.

Comment: I installed OpenCV after CUDA, so it shouldn't matter.